# Custom spark log location configuration in Azure databricks

Tags: pyspark, log4j, databricks, azure-databricks

We execute Databricks notebook pipelines using Azure data factory. We have configured 'Log delivery' option to get logs on DBFS. Currently, when two pipeline runs simelteneouly we are not clearly able to segregate logs per pipeline. It is possible using spark, when the instance is readily available in the databricks, to point logs directory to be ex /var/spark/{random_id}/logs/ ?

Comment: what do you mean can't segregate? Are you running ADF jobs with option "Use existing cluster" ? Please provide more details on ADF configuration, etc.

Comment: When two ADF pipelines run simultaneously. I get logs from two pipelines in the stdout file so I can not segregate them. I have specified dbfs:/cluster-logs/0507-083455-leaky918 in the logging field.

Comment: if each of jobs are using the new clusters, then you need to configure location to the `dbfs:/cluster-logs/` - Databricks job will create a separate folder for each new cluster created for job.  If you're using "Existing cluster" then you can't do that

Comment: I am trying alternative ways to do it using overriding the log4j setting of spark instance.